# iPhone sharing question

Tags: iphone, apple-id, sharing, home-sharing

My husband & I share an Apple ID.  We want to continue sharing contacts and calendars.  Can this be done if we use separate  Apple ID s? We don't want to keep getting each others messages and calls.

Comment: Use [family sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) & see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36320/what-are-some-best-practices-for-a-family-sharing-a-single-apple-id?rq=1

Comment: This can be done on your own but since it would be the first time you set this up, I recommend getting Apple's help.  If you're close to an Apple store, make a Genius appointment.  If not, and one of the devices is still under warranty, contact Apple via chat or phone and have them walk you thru it.  Having someone with you while you do this is extremely helpful.

Comment: @fbara if you made that an answer I'd upvote it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. However, since Apple ID's aren't designed to be used with multiple users [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201060) would be a more suitable option.

To do this you'll first want to [turn off the syncing features you don't want in Settings > iCloud](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2613).

To avoid receiving each other's calls, etc you'll want to [disable some of the Continuity features](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204681) like "iPhone Cellular Calls".

Also, ensure that [Automatic Downloads](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202180) aren't turned on in Settings > iTunes & App Store to avoid your partner's purchases being downloaded to your device automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on your own but since it would be the first time you set this up, I recommend getting [Apple's help](https://support.apple.com/contact). If you're close to an Apple store, make a Genius appointment. If not, and one of the devices is still under warranty, contact Apple via chat or phone and have them walk you thru it. Having someone with you while you do this is extremely helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can share a calendar. Based on my personal experience, you could make a Google Calendar and sign in to whatever devices with that Google account and have it set to sync calendars. I think it could also sync contacts, but I haven't tried that. That way contacts and calendars is separate from your Apple IDs.